# Why Plotly is not working on Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-science, jupyter-lab

I had to update my Macbook Air's iOS (Catalina), since I updated to this iOS's version, plotly stop working on my Jupyter-lab's enviroment.

I already followed the Getting Started's steps showed on plotly website:

```
$ pip install jupyterlab==1.2 "ipywidgets>=7.5"
```

When I run a random example, it shows an empty white block:

[image]

The libraries that I was importing (The ones that worked before):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode, plot,iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: I have the same issue here, I think the currently jupyter lab and it's extenssion do support plot.ly yet, but jupyter notebook does show the figure.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. where inline plots work in jupyter notebook but not lab

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the relevant JupyterLab extensions installed, as per our Getting Started guide here: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/

If you're having trouble, here is our troubleshooting guide: https://plot.ly/python/troubleshooting/